# How to run and test Framework7 app locally?

Tags: html-framework-7

I'm trying to learn framework7. I've downloaded an already made template from here:

https://framework7.io/templates/

I've actually downloaded this template which is the most basic one:

https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-template-single-view

But when I run the **index.html** page in my browser and when i try to navigate to other pages like **about.html**, I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/ME/Desktop/MYAPP/www/pages/about.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

is there any specific way to run and test framework7 apps locally on my computer?

This should be an easy, simple and obvious way so we can see what we are developing but i can't seem to find any solution for this!

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install localhost and access the app's file (index.html) via localhost like so:

```
http://localhost/myapp/wwww/
```

and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Install a local server package like xampp, uniserver, etc 
Copy app files to www directory of the installed server and access it on localhost via browser by going to:

> http://localhost

Comment: Could you provide more details about how to make it run on xampp? I copied all files into htdoc folder, but nothing works. All links lead to "object not found".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively
1)install live server extension to Visual Basic Code Editor.
2) open framework 7 code folder with Visual Studio Code and start live server(right click on code editor->Open With LiveServer.)